# NullPointerException in anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I have a simple Android Fragment `CreateAccountBookingFragment` which inherits from `CreateAccountFragment`, that has the following method :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    passwordTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                    || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                onSignUpClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

method `onSignUpClick()` is overridden in `CreateAccountBookingFragment`. 
Recently there was a bug caught :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.myapp.ui.auth.CreateAccountBookingFragment.onSignUpClick(CreateAccountBookingFragment.java:82)
   at com.myapp.ui.auth.CreateAccountFragment$1.onEditorAction(CreateAccountFragment.java:83)
   at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4594)
   at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:297)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I quite don't understand how it could throw `NullPointer`. It means that inner class is still alive and outer is not ? I though it's impossible. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here ? And what will be the solution to this. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Device the bug occurred : [Samsung GT P3113](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P3113TSYXAR-specs)

**Update** :
method `onSingUpClick()` is here :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@OnClick(R.id.frag_auth_sign_up_btn) // line 82, this is ButterKnife annotation
protected void onSignUpClick() {

    String email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

    int errorMsg = 0;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        errorMsg = R.string.enter_email;
    } else if (!Utils.isValidEmail(email)) {
        errorMsg = R.string.invaild_email;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        errorMsg = R.string.enter_password;
    } else if (!Utils.isValidPassword(password)) {
        errorMsg = R.string.invaild_password;
    } else if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
        errorMsg = R.string.network_not_connected;
    }

    if (errorMsg > 0) {
        ViewUtils.getInfoDialog(getActivity(), errorMsg).show();
    } else {
        showLoadingDialog();
        signUp(email, password);
    }
    ViewUtils.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: If a non-static inner class is Serializable, it serializes the outer class too, and might indeed produce or reloading an OuterClass.this being null when the OuterClass is not Serializable. _Though that is quite a special case._

Comment: post the contents of `onSignUpClick` and tell us what's line no 82)

Comment: Notice how it doesn't say onEditorAction is the problem it says onSignUpClick is the problem, specifically like 82.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa updated with the function `onSignUpClick()`. But as far as I understood, the exception says the problem is in calling the function, not inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the code of your `signUp()` function from the CreateAccountBookingFragment class? Are you in some way using `getActivity()` in that method?

There is chance that sometimes `getActivity()` returns null. It is most probably that error.  So in this case, add a null check on `getActivity()`,
that is:

```
if (getActivity()!=null){
    // only then do your singIn() method stuff 
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should ask for clarification to the original question in a comment.

Comment: it says i need 50 rep to comment , and so i m replying in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.  I'm curious if my 'solution' will work for you as well.  This problem is also occurring on a Samsung GT P3113 for me.

I moved the anonymous listener to the class itself eliminate the inner classs accessor.  for you that would mean adding TextView.OnEditorActionListener to the 'implements' part of your Fragment class definition and then implementing the onEditorAction() method in the fragment class.  That way the lifetime of the listener object is always the same as that of the fragment.  I know, it shouldn't be a problem, but since the NPE is occurring when it tries to invoke the method using the accessor object.. it seems to be working for me.

Comment: thanks for advice, will try and let know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something you are using in CreateAccountBookingFragment class, any variable used from outside the anonymous inner class has to be final or it will have an issue due to cloistering.

Comment: what about the fragment view itself  :) ? if its being accessed in code in his method onSignUpClick();